# How to address enhancement requests to Org-Mode team?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

For example, I would like Org-Mode to be able to read elisp variables or link abbreviations when input as value for `#+EXPORT_FILE_NAME:`.

Where and how should I ask for that?

Comment: See [Ways to contribute](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contribute.html)

Comment: In general, the project's website will generally contain a pointer to how to submit bugs and RFEs, where the mailing list is (if there is one), what you have to do to contribute code, etc. You might have to look around to find what you are looking for - and if that is hard to do, that feedback can also be valuable to devs. In the case of Org mode, the website is https://orgmode.org .

Comment: I don't know how mailing lists work, I'm currently reading the documentation provided by Org Mode on this topic. It seems a heavy process to have to receive all mails people exchange about org mode.… Wouldn't it be simpler to manage feature requests through GitHub or a similar web app?

Comment: Ah, youngsters  - mailing lists are not good enough for them :-) In any case, you don't have to receive mail. Many people keep up to date by following the associated newsgroup `gmane.emacs.orgmode` - or they modify their subscription to get daily digests of all the traffic. But Org mode is not on Github and there is no other web app: if you want to participate in the development of Org mode (or Emacs or the Linux kernel for that matter), mailing lists are the way they do it.

Comment: @NickD if a mailing list isn't good go figure a newsgrup :)